# How to set x coordinates as hours in core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am drawing a ScatterPlot using core-plot framework. My x coordinates are hours starting from 0 AM to 12 PM . How i can set these as my x coordinates ? please help me .. thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several recent questions dealing with how to format dates in Core Plot (for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998182/core-plot-and-nsdate-iphone)). Use the same procedure, but set up your CPTimeFormatter to show the time, not the date.